# Using strings with hashmaps

Tags: java

How would I use a `String` to specify a specific `HashMap`.

Eg:

```
public static ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> age = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>(); 
String s = "age";
s.get("Nick");
```

Comment: "*use a string to specify a specific hashmap.*" that is incoherent.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: s is String in your case. I guess you meant age.get("Nick") instead of s.get("Nick")

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Map a person's name to their age, you need

```
Map<String,Integer> age = new HashMap<>(); // only use ConcurrentHashMap if you intend
                                           // to use that Map from multiple threads
...
age.put("Nick",42);
...
int nicksAge = age.get("Nick");
```

Comment: Ok, but what I was looking for was temporarily using the string to reference the map's name. If you look in my example, I'm using String 's' which has been assigned "age" to be used as hashmap's name which is age. (If that makes sense)

Comment: @NickMandylas What you tried is not possible. `s` is a `String`, not a `HashMap`. It doesn't have a get method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HashMapTest {
    public static HashMap<String, Integer> ageMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ageMap.put("Nick", 12);
        Integer age = ageMap.get("Nick");
        System.out.println(age);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Generics

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Generics allows you to specify a type for a map. So instead of using

```
public static ConcurrentHashMap age = new ConcurrentHashMap();
```

You could use

```
public static Map<String, Short> age = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

or any other form of map for example

```
public static Map<String, Integer> ageMap = new HashMap<>();
```

This simplifies the get and put operations.

Instead of writing a code such as

```
Object o = ageMap.get("Nick");
if(o instanceof Integer) {
    Integer age = (Integer) o;
}
```

You could simply write

```
Integer age = ageMap.get("Nick");
```